# Can not view serial data on Arduino Micro

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have written some serial code which justs outputs 'X'. Using the arduinos IdE Serial monitor I can view this very nicely.

I can not view this data on hyperserialterminal though, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

be sure tho choose the correct serial port, that nothing else is using that serial port (like serial monitor), to choose the matching baudrate and that other options are right (8n1)

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Micro requires the DTR and RTS pin of the comport to be ON, something the Arduino monitor does!

Hence with my serial interface i had to set the DTR and RTS ON, to beable to receive!

Comment: Can you mark this answer as accepted, so that it doesn't show up on the unanswered questions list?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Out put of the Arduino pins of serial monitor are TTL output. If you use USB to TTL output can connect to tx and Rx pins . Then only you can see the terminal window.
Also check The Ground pins. aLSO PASTE YOUR CODE WHAT YOUR ARE TRYING TO PRINT